# .then() is not a function thrown when returning jQuery promises

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my `createUserData()` function:

```
createUserData(user) {
    const dfd = new $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        url: './awesome/user',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: user,
    })
    .then((response) => {
        dfd.resolve(response);
    })
    .fail((xhr) => {
        // do stuff with errors
        dfd.reject(errorMsg);
    });

    return dfd.promise;
}
```

And I want to be able to call it where ever...

```
createUserData(user).then((response) => {
    // do more stuff with that response
    // fire off other functions
    // But I can't get here...
});
```

I get `createUserData(...).then() is not a function`. Am I using promises wrong? I don't understand, I'm returning the promise in my function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `return dfd.promise()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke the promise method:

```
return dfd.promise();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could directly return the $.ajax and concatenate that using the .done() and .fail().

Btw in your code the issue should be

```
return dfd.promise();
```